# Linker errors with BLAS/LAPACK symbols (snrm2_, sdot_, etc) when building Fortran project with gfortran on Windows

Tags: fortran, linker-errors, gfortran, undefined-reference, blas

I'm trying to build the [Elmer finite element software (version 9.0)](https://github.com/ElmerCSC/elmerfem/tree/wip/windows) using gfortran 10.2.0 and OpenBLAS 0.3.15 libraries on Windows 10. I'm running into linker errors when creating the shared libraries, where it cannot find references to various BLAS/LAPACK symbols like snrm2_, sdot_, dnrm2_, etc.

In my CMake configuration, I'm finding OpenBLAS using find_package(BLAS) and find_package(LAPACK), then linking to these libraries when creating the shared libraries for the Elmer solvers.

The linker command generated by CMake looks like this:

```
/mingw64/bin/gfortran.exe -fallow-argument-mismatch -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -shared -o msys-fhuti.dll -Wl,-Bsymbolic -Wl,--out-implib,libfhuti.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 CMakeFiles/fhuti.dir/huti_aux.F90.o CMakeFiles/fhuti.dir/huti_bicgstab_2.F90.o etc.. -lffi -lopenblas -lgfortran -lm
```

And the resulting linker errors:

```
undefined reference to `snrm2_'
undefined reference to `sdot_'
undefined reference to `dnrm2_'
etc...
```

I've tried:

- Verified OpenBLAS libraries work correctly when compiled/linked manually using gfortran
- Linked libraries explicitly using target_link_libraries() instead of find_package()
- Used different combinations of linker flags like -Wl,-Bsymbolic
- I checked gfortran version, OpenBLAS architecture matches my system

But I still get the same undefined reference errors. How can I fix this linker issue when using gfortran and OpenBLAS on Windows? Any ideas what might be going wrong with how the OpenBLAS symbols are getting resolved?

Any help or pointers on how I can resolve these gfortran/BLAS linker errors would be greatly appreciated!

**P.S.** Here is the complete error message (also mentioned [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/fortran/comments/15ywugn/linking_error_with_gfortran_undefined_reference/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)):

```
Linking Fortran shared library msys-fhuti.dll

cd "/c/Users/Foo/OneDrive - Bar/Desktop/Elmer/elmerfem/build/fhutiter/src" && /usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/fhuti.dir/link.txt --verbose=1

/mingw64/bin/gfortran.exe -fallow-argument-mismatch -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -shared -Wl,--enable-auto-import -o msys-fhuti.dll -Wl,--out-implib,libfhuti.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 CMakeFiles/fhuti.dir/huti_aux.F90.o CMakeFiles/fhuti.dir/huti_bicgstab_2.F90.o CMakeFiles/fhuti.dir/huti_bicgstab.F90.o CMakeFiles/fhuti.dir/huti_cg.F90.o CMakeFiles/fhuti.dir/huti_cgs.F90.o CMakeFiles/fhuti.dir/huti_gmres.F90.o CMakeFiles/fhuti.dir/huti_qmr.F90.o CMakeFiles/fhuti.dir/huti_tfqmr.F90.o CMakeFiles/fhuti.dir/huti_interfaces.F90.o CMakeFiles/fhuti.dir/huti_sfe.F90.o

C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/fhuti.dir/huti_sfe.F90.o:huti_sfe.F90:(.rdata$.refptr.snrm2_[.refptr.snrm2_]+0x0): undefined reference to `snrm2_'

C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/fhuti.dir/huti_sfe.F90.o:huti_sfe.F90:(.rdata$.refptr.sdot_[.refptr.sdot_]+0x0): undefined reference to `sdot_'

C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/fhuti.dir/huti_sfe.F90.o:huti_sfe.F90:(.rdata$.refptr.dnrm2_[.refptr.dnrm2_]+0x0): undefined reference to `dnrm2_'

C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/fhuti.dir/huti_sfe.F90.o:huti_sfe.F90:(.rdata$.refptr.ddot_[.refptr.ddot_]+0x0): undefined reference to `ddot_'

C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/fhuti.dir/huti_sfe.F90.o:huti_sfe.F90:(.rdata$.refptr.scnrm2_[.refptr.scnrm2_]+0x0): undefined reference to `scnrm2_'

C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/fhuti.dir/huti_sfe.F90.o:huti_sfe.F90:(.rdata$.refptr.cdotc_[.refptr.cdotc_]+0x0): undefined reference to `cdotc_'

C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/fhuti.dir/huti_sfe.F90.o:huti_sfe.F90:(.rdata$.refptr.dznrm2_[.refptr.dznrm2_]+0x0): undefined reference to `dznrm2_'

C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/fhuti.dir/huti_sfe.F90.o:huti_sfe.F90:(.rdata$.refptr.zdotc_[.refptr.zdotc_]+0x0): undefined reference to `zdotc_'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

make[2]: *** [fhutiter/src/CMakeFiles/fhuti.dir/build.make:234: fhutiter/src/msys-fhuti.dll] Error 1

make[2]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/Foo/OneDrive - Bar/Desktop/Elmer/elmerfem/build'

make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:16866: fhutiter/src/CMakeFiles/fhuti.dir/all] Error 2

make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/Foo/OneDrive - Bar/Desktop/Elmer/elmerfem/build'

make: *** [Makefile:169: all] Error 2
```

Comment: Please do not link to useful details (such as the complete errors messages) on another site, copy/paste in your question instead. And BTW, the gfortran command that is shown on the reddit page is not the same as the one shown in your question. Which one is supposed to be relevant ?

Comment: @PierU thanks for the comment. I tried to summarize the error messages and condense them as much as possible. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: Linking to an external site to get useful and complete details is a mistake in itself, as the content of the external site may disappear at some point. Moreover, I repeat that the gfortran commands differ between your question here and your question on reddit: in the latter case blas and lapack libraries are apparently not specified in the gfortran command, so no wonder why there are undefined references.

Comment: @PierU added the complete error message.

Comment: Thanks. And I repeat what I've already written: the gfortran command line in the full report does not refer to the blas and lapack libraries, so no wonder why you have undefined references/

Comment: @PierU any idea how to fix the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/ElmerCSC/elmerfem/blob/wip/windows/CMakeLists.txt) file?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with cmake...